Can't add an exception to Windows Defender antivirus
I finally got rid of nagware antivirus (AVG Free) because almost everyone says Windows Defender is perfectly good enough on its own.
But now I can't run a certain program (which I'm very sure is safe, and didn't trigger anything in AVG).
So, I go to Exclusions under virus & threat settings, click "Add an exclusion", "File" and select the .exe I want to exclude.
But then windows just tells me "Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or PUP".
So you can't tell windows something isn't a virus, because windows says it's a virus!
A major further annoyance, by the way, is that I never got any kind of message at all (program just silently failed to run) until I tried running it as administrator.
I cannot put up with an antivirus solution which doesn't tell me what it has blocked, and then won't let me unblock it. Please tell me I don't have to go back to nagware :(

What software is it that you're trying to run? Can you submit it to VirusTotal to check it out? It is very possible to get a software that is legitimate from a site that loads that legitimate installer with badware. Is this a discrete executable ("portable app") or an application installed in Program Files?

@music2myear Checked, no problems detected.

@music2myear Application installed in ProgramFiles

Is Defender running the latest definition files? How up-to-date is your Windows install? Online resources indicate this message will come when you try to access or move files outside Defender, but I haven't yet found any mentioning this is happening when you try to add a file as an exception in Defender.

Exclusions in Defender can be added manually. Open a PowerShell window and run this:
add-mppreference -exclusionprocess 'c:\path\to\program.exe'
Add-MpPreference -ExclusionProcess adds a single executable exception to Defender effective immediately. After running this, you can open the Defender UI and you should see that executable listed in the Exceptions list.
However, resources online suggest that false positives like this can be due to not being fully updated, or there being some corruption in Defender or the OS. Make sure Windows and Defender are fully updated, and run sfc /scannow, or perform a "Repair Upgrade" using Windows media on a thumbdrive if the previous steps don't fix this.

Having to use Powershell to perform basic configuration, not to mention the fact that the program was blocked silently (failed to start with no error dialog) would indicate to me that Defender needs a lot more work before it can replace 3rd party anti-virus! I guess I just have to find something which nags a lot less than AVG.

I think you may have missed the point: PowerShell is not a "work around". Add-MpPreference is a built-in default method for configuring Defender. Your Defender UI may be having problems, and I gave suggestions for resolving this. Defender is the best of free AVs. If you want to pay for an AV product for reasons, I recommend BitDefender from personal experience. But you have likely system corruption that you should address.

Windows is a near-exclusively graphical OS aimed at the general population. and the need to open any kind of command prompt, for any reason, should be regarded as a failure on the part of Windows, or of whatever third party software is requiring you to do so! Always!

I reinstalled windows recently, so I'm not keen to do so again. However, all AV sometimes flag false positives, I don't see why a false positive should be indicative of OS/Defender  misconfiguration.

Anyhow, thanks for the BitDefender recommendation.
